# AutoSize vertically while AutoEllipsis horizontally on label control

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize

I want to place a label on the bottom left corner of an user control.
The control may vary in size by horizontally and vertically.
When the horizontal resize is reduced so that the label cannot be shown fully,
I want the AutoEllipsis to kick in.
But on the other hand, I dont want my control floating from the left bottom,
because the height of the label is not autosized (which makes the text stay above a few pixels higher than autosized label).

So I want to know how to set AutoEllipsis horizontally but keep AutoSize vertically on a label control. Help me out.

[image: AutoSize = true; AutoEllipsis = false]
[image: Autosize = false; AutoEllipsis = true]

Comment: winforms? asp.net? wpf?

Comment: C# winform. But does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set these properties for the label:

```
AutoEllipsis = true
Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left
AutoSize = false
```

**Update:**
Try these properties:

```
AutoEllipsis = true
TextAlign = TopLeft
Anchor = Bottom, Left, Right
AutoSize = false
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what exactly do you want. Could you provide some pictures?

Comment: I added the picture to help you understand.

Comment: Once again. You want: **Horizontally - autoEllipsis, Vertically - align bottom left, not resize** or:  **Horizontally - not autoEllipsis, Vertically - align bottom left, resize the label**?